# How to partition/slice rows horizontally in a data frame by contiguous occurrence of same value in column(s) to generate a statistical info in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Please find attached snap and provide me how to reach to a solution of desired output mentioned in image description?

[image]

Code to generate input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':pd.date_range('2022-04-30 00:00:00', periods=19, freq='S'),
                  'fault_code':['A']*4+['B']*4+['A']*2+['C']*5+['B']*2+['A']*2})
```

Comment: Could you provide the details using text, rather than using an [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp':pd.date_range('2022-04-30 00:00:00', periods=19, freq='S'),
                  'fault_code':['A']*4+['B']*4+['A']*2+['C']*5+['B']*2+['A']*2})

df['group'] = (df['fault_code'] != df['fault_code'].shift()).cumsum()

df_s = df.groupby(['fault_code','group'], as_index=False)['timestamp']\
         .agg(lambda x: int(np.ptp(x).total_seconds()))

df_out = df_s.groupby('fault_code').agg(occurrence=('fault_code','count'),
                               duration=('timestamp', list),
                               total_duration=('timestamp','sum'))

df_out
```

Output:

```
            occurrence   duration  total_duration
fault_code                                       
A                    3  [3, 1, 1]               5
B                    2     [3, 1]               4
C                    1        [4]               4
```

Comment: that df['group'] line is powerful... Thanks for that answer!

Comment: I ran the given solution but I get error like - "AttributeError: 'numpy.timedelta64' object has no attribute 'total_seconds'" – 
Siddhartha Saha
 33 secs ago

Comment: Maybe upgrade numpy...

Comment: I am using Python 3.9.7
scipy: 1.7.1
numpy: 1.20.3
matplotlib: 3.4.3
pandas: 1.3.4
which version of numpy are you using?

Comment: Does that error happen with this exact code?

Comment: yes, the error happen with the exact code. what can I use instead of total_seconds()

Comment: `np.ptp(pd.Series(pd.date_range('2022-03-01', periods=10, freq='H'))).total_seconds()` Does this command work for you?

Comment: Try this instead `df_s = df.groupby(['fault_code','group'], as_index=False)['timestamp']\
         .agg(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).total_seconds())`

Comment: @Scott Boston It is a great help from you, I appreciate you . Thanks